# “The procedure entry point… could not be located” in the wrong DLL

Tags: c++, haskell, dll

I have created a DLL from Haskell code and I am calling this DLL from C++. My application works fine when I run it in Debug mode in Visual Studio 2010, but when I make a Release build and install it, I get the error

> The procedure entry point GetDataChunk could not be located in the dynamic link library AdvancedMath.dll.

AdvancedMath.dll is my Haskell-based DLL. The weird thing is that the function GetDataChunk isn’t in that DLL—it’s in another DLL I link against, and nothing about *that* DLL or my application’s use of it changed when I added the Haskell DLL.

This error message seems to be saying that Windows is confused about which functions live in which DLLs. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: _"What could be going wrong here?"_ Too many things to give you a concise answer.

Comment: copy your dll file into system32 directory of windows and then try.

Comment: @userNishant This is part of an application that will be distributed to customers and installed on their computers. There’s no way I’m installing anything in system32.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in Visual Studio 2010 Release mode (Haskell dll functions are not imported by exe built in Release mode hence Haskell dll is not loaded, in Debug imports are present and it works fine).

The same exe project built in Release mode using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and Visual Studio 2015 RC works fine.

Comment: I'm confused. The question does not include the source, or even a link to the source. How do you know what it does in a different version?

Comment: @dfeuer "Hello World" type of Haskell dll is facing a similar problem - works with Debug but not with Release exe when build under VS 2010. OP will need to post a reproducible example if that's not the same problem.

Comment: Wow, interesting. I'm using VS 2013 and have never had a problem with Haskell DLLs. I've never tried VS 2010.

Comment: I’m tied to VS 2010 for the moment so this is a bummer. I appreciate the research, though.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using .def file to define exports? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx

After you create it, you must edit project properties Linker->Input->Module definition file

Comment: Yes, I use a .def file to define the exports from SpectrumMath.dll and I have verified (with Dependency Walker) that the expected functions are visible.

Comment: @bdesham In dependency walker there is one panel showing dll exports and another what exe is importing, it's easy to get confused by this, did you check in the correct panel? Another way to check the same: `dumpbin /imports your.exe`. Anyway even you see the imports there is clearly something broken in VS2010 Release mode, you could try with newer version of Visual Studio as I wrote in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31486183/4899330) (probably without .def file to exclude possibility of something being wrong in .def file too).