# Looking function in wrong DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ffmpeg

I link `avcodec.lib, .... avxxx.lib (ffmpeg library)` to my vs2008 project, but show the error message box **"procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library"** while double click it.

I check my program with DLL dependencies tool, it shows the program try to find DXVA2CreateDirect3DDeviceManager9 in avcodec.dll. It is impossible to find that function definitely.

I also saw someone has the same problem with me.
[The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library - looking in wrong DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867607/the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library-loo)

This post solve me problem, but why?

Comment: It seems vc2008 bug.
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12633

Comment: According to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416185/the-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located-in-the-wrong-dll/31486183 It seems an issue, I suggest you could try to use vs2017 or newer version of VS.